# Не отрабатывает функция рефреша и добавления значений в базу данных

Tags: веб-программирование, php, тестирование

Добрый день, 
Накидал скрипт для автоматизации своей работы и хотел его запихать в функцию, ну что бы отправляя с разных форм аргументы в эту функцию что бы рефрешить значения на железках можно было, что бы еще эти значения в базу заносились, а если железка с таким ip уже есть, то что бы тупо апдейт в базе был. Но в программировании я слаб и не понимаю почему если вынести эту страшную конструкцию из фигурных скобок функции рефреш и поместить ее в else место вызова функции то вся конструкция работает как нужно, а если передавать аргументы через функцию то php на бесконечное время задумывается, аргументы же передаются. Ошибки сам у себя к сожалению не нашел. Наверное я опять каких то фундаментальных вещей не понял =(

```
 $tthDescr=$_POST['description'];
 $tthIp=$_POST['ip'];

 function refresh($thIp,$thDescr) {

$mysql_database="AmplifierOptic";
$mysql_username="root";
$mysql_password="123456";
$mysql_host="localhost";

 mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_username,$mysql_password) or die("CAN NOT CONNECT THIS MYSQL");
  mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die("CAN NOT ACCEPT THIS DB");

    $thinSNMP[0] = snmpget("$thIp", "public", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.17409.1.11.3.0");
    $thinSNMP[1] = eregi_replace("INTEGER:","",$thinSNMP[0]);
    $thoutSNMP[0] = snmpget("$thIp", "public", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.17409.1.11.2.0");
    $thoutSNMP[1] = eregi_replace("INTEGER:","",$thoutSNMP[0]);
    $thmodeSNMP[0] = snmpget("$thIp", "public", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.17409.1.11.82.0");
    $thmodeSNMP[1] = eregi_replace("INTEGER:","",$thmodeSNMP[0]);
    $thgSetSNMP[0] = snmpget("$thIp", "public", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.17409.1.11.80.0");
    $thgSetSNMP[1] = eregi_replace("INTEGER:","",$thgSetSNMP[0]);
    $thpSetSNMP[0] = snmpget("$thIp", "public", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.17409.1.11.11.0");
    $thpSetSNMP[1] = eregi_replace("INTEGER:","",$thpSetSNMP[0]);

     if ($thmodeSNMP[1]=="1")

     {
        $thmodeSNMP[1]=gain;
        $thSetSNMP=$thgSetSNMP[1];
                          }
     else {
         $thmodeSNMP[1]=power;
         $thSetSNMP=$thpSetSNMP[1];
                        }

     while ( $thinSNMP[0]=="" && $thoutSNMP[0]=="" && $thmodeSNMP[0]=="0" && $thSetSNMP=="") 
  {
         sleep(2);
     $thinSNMP[0] = snmpget("$thIp", "public", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.17409.1.11.3.0");
     $thinSNMP[1] = eregi_replace("INTEGER:","",$thinSNMP[0]);
     $thoutSNMP[0] = snmpget("$thIp", "public", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.17409.1.11.2.0");
     $thoutSNMP[1] = eregi_replace("INTEGER:","",$thoutSNMP[0]);
     $thmodeSNMP[0] = snmpget("$thIp", "public", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.17409.1.11.82.0");
     $thmodeSNMP[1] = eregi_replace("INTEGER:","",$thmodeSNMP[0]);
     $thgSetSNMP[0] = snmpget("$thIp", "public", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.17409.1.11.80.0");
     $thgSetSNMP[1] = eregi_replace("INTEGER:","",$thgSetSNMP[0]);
     $thpSetSNMP[0] = snmpget("$thIp", "public", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.17409.1.11.11.0");
     $thpSetSNMP[1] = eregi_replace("INTEGER:","",$thpSetSNMP[0]);
     $thmodeSNMP[0] = snmpget("$thIp", "public", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.17409.1.11.82.0");
     $thmodeSNMP[1] = eregi_replace("INTEGER:","",$thmodeSNMP[0]);
     if ($thmodeSNMP[1]=="1")

     {
        $thmodeSNMP[1]=gain;
        $thSetSNMP=$thgSetSNMP[1];
                          }
     else {
         $thmodeSNMP[1]=power;
         $thSetSNMP=$thpSetSNMP[1];
                        }
     }

 if ( $thinSNMP[1]=="" || $thoutSNMP[1]=="" || $thmodeSNMP[1]=="" || $thSetSNMP[1]=="")
      {
         echo "Не получены значения snmp! <br>";
      }

      else {

          $search_ip= mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM `AmplifierOptic`.`device` WHERE ip LIKE '%$thIp%'");
          if (!$search_ip){
      echo "Ошибка при запросе";
          exit(mysql_error());
                }
         $myarray = array(); // создаем пустой массив, страховка
            $n = mysql_num_rows($search_ip); // Узнаем количество элементов в выборке

            for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
            {
    $myarray[] = mysql_fetch_array($search_ip);
                    }

             foreach($myarray as $value){}
             if ($value['ip']== $thIp)
                {
                 $sql="UPDATE `device` SET `description`='$thDescr', `in`='$thinSNMP[1]', `out`='$thoutSNMP[1]',`mode`='$thmodeSNMP[1]', `set`='$thSetSNMP[1]'  WHERE ip LIKE '%$thIp%'"; 
                 $addsql=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
                  echo "Устройство с таким айпи уже есть в базе, значения для этого устройства обновлены";  
                }

               if ($value['ip']!= $thIp)
               {
                     $sql="INSERT INTO `AmplifierOptic`.`device` (`id`, `description`, `ip`, `in`, `out`, `mode`, `set`) VALUES ('$count', '$thDescr', '$thIp', '$thinSNMP[1]', '$thoutSNMP[1]', '$thmodeSNMP[1]', '$thSetSNMP[1]');";
                     $addsql=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
                     echo "Запись в базу добавлена";  
                }

                                mysql_free_result($search_ip);
           }
           mysql_close();
}

 if ($tthIp=="" || $tthDescr=="")
 {
     echo "error: empty rows";
 }

 else 
     {
   refresh($tthDescr,$tthIp);

     }
```

Comment: В такой простыне без пол литра не разобраться...

___

    foreach($myarray as $value){}

Зачем это?

___


        $thmodeSNMP[1] = gain;
        $thmodeSNMP[1] = power;

`gain, power` - это что? строки? Если да, то тогда надо писать `$thmodeSNMP[1] = 'gain';`

___

    eregi_replace()

Функция помечена как deprecated, стоит заменить на `str_replace`

___ 

Есть такая крутая конструкция в `SQL: INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` - она решит ваши проблемы с проверкой на существование записи в БД.

Comment: Я так полагаю у вас в теле цикла 

    foreach($myarray as $value){}

должна быть конструкция с if  и insert или update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте запустить вот этот [**код**](http://pastebin.com/Z7Tind7Z), если опять повиснет, будем смотреть дальше.

Comment: Да спасибо за подсказки и указание на помарки, когда написал этот пост появилось сразу же пару идей почему может не работать)
Со всеми вашими замечаниями согласен, думал их убрать чуть позже так как на работоспособность они не влияли, в поле id стоит автоинкрементирование, просто быстрее писал функционал. За наводку на "INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" отдельное спасибо.

Comment: От части ваш ответ оказался правдивым, были ошибки, ну суть крылась в том что железка не отвечала на один из оидов, по этому все "задумывалось", сейчас функция работает, код рабочий. Но все же спасибо, к замечаниям прислушился.